# mysql how do I change the column id from varchars to ints and autoincreasing?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

How do I make the change of the column ID in the table to ints and auto-increment through phpmyadmin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no primary key, try this statement -

```
ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Otherwise, you can run a script like this -

```
ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: IF id column is not already defined as key, MySql fails to alter that column ;)

Comment: @Marco Yes, you are right. I have added second query yet. Thanks;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
CHANGE ID ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps :

1) Make the datatype of columns for autoincrement as BIGINT
2) Make the same column as primary key.
3) Then add the auto inrement option as shown in the image 
[AUTO INCREMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxY9J.gif)